# Почему Invision Power Board не отправляет письма?

Tags: php, email, ipb

Добрый день! Есть форум на Invision Power Board 3.4.6. Внезапно он прекратил отправлять e-mail как администраторам, так и пользователям. При тестировании отправки почты "Поддержка - диагностика - проверка Email" пишет "Email успешно отправлен" - но ничего не приходит.

Интересно, что если написать тестовый скрипт, использующий почтовый класс classEmail из файла \ipsKernel\classEmail.php - то тестовые письма ходят. Т.е. не работает отправка из самого IPB, хотя в функцию mail() в итоге все необходимые параметры ($to, $subject, $message, $rfc_headers) передаются и имеют вполне корректные значения, которые я глядел через echo/var_dump. И mail() выдаёт true, несмотря на то, что письмо не доходит ни до каких адресатов.

В каком направлении копать?

PS. Хостинг SWEB, техподдержка внятного ничего не говорит. Типа, у них всё ОК. В логах php/apache ошибок нет.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена!

1) изначально почта не ходила, потому что на сервере обновили PHP до версии 5.5. Для работы IPB с ним необходимо скачать патч на класс отправки почты вот отсюда: https://www.invisionpower.com/support/kb/_/34-emails-may-not-send-after-a-recent-php-upgrade-r78

2) далее почта не ходила, потому что на mail.ru включена новая антиспам-политика DMARC, когда от имени @mail.ru теперь просто так нельзя отправлять письма на @mail.ru. Как только заменили ящик@mail.ru в поле "От" на другой, почта стала нормально ходить на mail и gmail. Вот такие пироги. Подробнее о DMARC:
https://corp.mail.ru/ru/press/releases/9593/

Answer (score 0):

Возможно их адрес попал в blacklist или какие то изменения в конфигурации. Тогда нужно смотреть логи почтового сервера, а не php/apache. Попробуйте изменить Mail Delivery Method на SMTP, используя например Gmail сервер.

Comment: А я выше писал, что проблема уже решена :) Спасибо)